# InternetOpenUrl Unhandled exception

Tags: c++

My code:

```
HINTERNET connect = InternetOpen(L"MyBrowser", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
->> HINTERNET OpenAddress = InternetOpenUrl(connect, L"web page", NULL, 0, 
INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);

char dataReceived[5000];
std::string received;
DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
while (InternetReadFile(OpenAddress, dataReceived, 5000, &NumberOfBytesRead) && NumberOfBytesRead)
{
    received += std::string(dataReceived);
}
```

This code is run in a loop, and after several dozen repetitions, an unhandled exception pops up. I have highlighted the line ->>*

I realized that the stack has overflowed, but please tell me how to clear it? Or am I wrong?

Exception:
[exception*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlAXu.png)

And values ​​in variables:
[values*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DKKR.png)

If I try to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

void data();

void test(std::string received) {
    data();
    Sleep(1);
}

void data(HINTERNET connect) {
    HINTERNET OpenAddress = InternetOpenUrl(connect, L"web page", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);
    char dataReceived[5000];
    std::string received;
    DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
    while (InternetReadFile(OpenAddress, dataReceived, 5000, &NumberOfBytesRead) && NumberOfBytesRead)
    {
        received += std::string(dataReceived);
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(OpenAddress);
    test(received);
}

int main() {
    HINTERNET connect = InternetOpen(L"MyBrowser", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    data(connect);
    InternetCloseHandle(connect);
}
```

This error pops up: LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl data(void)" (?data@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl test(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits,class std::allocator >)" (?test@@YAXV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

This is a shortened example of my program*

Comment: The problem likely exists because of code not shown here.  Stack overflow is often the result of recursion or _very large_ variables on the stack.  Please try to create a [mre] that exhibits this problem.

Comment: Ok, I will make an example

Comment: "_This code is run in a loop_" - Are you calling `InternetOpen` more than once in the program? If so, why? Call it once at the start and then `InternetCloseHandle` when you're done.

Comment: I can't get it to run outside of the procedure. I have added a shortened code.

Comment: @exiperon I already answered the stack overflow issue on your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66535810/).  The linker issue is because you are declaring the `data` function as `void data()` and calling it as `data()`, but you implemented it as `void data(HINTERNET)`, so the linker can't find an implementation for a no-parameter `data()`.  The declaration and implement have to match.

Comment: I apologize for my stupidity. Thanks for the answer!