# Move HINTERNET connect outside the procedure

Tags: c++

This is a shortened version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

void data();

void test(std::string received) {
    data();
    Sleep(1);
}

void data() {
    - >>HINTERNET connect = InternetOpen(L"MyBrowser", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    HINTERNET OpenAddress = InternetOpenUrl(connect, L"web page", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);
    char dataReceived[5000];
    std::string received;
    DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
    while (InternetReadFile(OpenAddress, dataReceived, 5000, &NumberOfBytesRead) && NumberOfBytesRead)
    {
        received += std::string(dataReceived);
    }
    - >>InternetCloseHandle(connect);
    InternetCloseHandle(OpenAddress);
    test(received);
}

int main() {
    data();
}
```

Please tell me how to normally move the selected lines (- >>) outside the function to run them once?

Answer (score 0):

Change `data()` and `test()` to take an `HINTERNET` as a parameter, and then `main()` can create the `HINTERNET` to pass in, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <urlmon.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "urlmon.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

void data(HINTERNET connect);

void test(HINTERNET connect, std::string received) {
    data(connect);
    Sleep(1);
}

void data(HINTERNET connect) {
    HINTERNET OpenAddress = InternetOpenUrl(connect, L"web page", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);
    char dataReceived[5000];
    std::string received;
    DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
    while (InternetReadFile(OpenAddress, dataReceived, 5000, &NumberOfBytesRead) && NumberOfBytesRead)
    {
        received += std::string(dataReceived);
    }
    InternetCloseHandle(OpenAddress);
    test(connect, received);
}

int main() {
    HINTERNET connect = InternetOpen(L"MyBrowser", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    data(connect);
    InternetCloseHandle(connect);
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this. It throws an exception Unhandled exception at 0x00AB5AA9 in learning.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x004C2000) in chkstk.asm.

Comment: Make sense, since you have an endless recursion loop (`data()` calls `test()`, which calls `data()`, which calls `test()`, and so on...) that eats up stack space until it overflows. Every function call pushes data on the call stack. In your case, pushing more and more data until eventually the stack runs out of space. You need to break the recursion, such as by using an iterative loop instead, or a timer.

Comment: I apologize for my stupidity. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can you please answer one more question? I noticed that the stack overflows after 143 repetitions, can I somehow clear it to continue execution further?

Comment: @exiperon No. The previous function calls are still on the call stack, they can't clear their data from the stack until they are allowed to exit. The correct solution is to not use recursion to begin with.